# C++: Differences between 2 arrays

Tags: c++, c++11, set

I have two unsorted random access arrays of a single simple element type (int/string/etc, so has all comparison operators, can be hashed, etc.). There should not be duplicate elements in either array.

Looking for a general algorthim that given these arrays A and B will tell me:

1. What elements are in both A and B
2. What elements are in A but not B
3. What elements are in B but not A

I guess I could do this with the set operators as below, but is there a faster solution (e.g. one that doesnt require me to build two sorted sets)?

```
r1 = std::set_intersection(a,b);
r2 = std::set_difference(a,b);
r3 = std::set_difference(b,a);
```

Comment: 99% sure the best solution would be to just sort both arrays, which will cost you O(nlog(n)), any other solution I see is O(n^2)

Comment: And then use those 3 functions? Or there a better algorthim to take all three cases into account (O(min(a.size(),b.size()) perhaps even)?

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Have you profiled your application and found out that these operations are the cause of bottleneck in your program?

Comment: @FireLancer after then you can tell in linear time for each element if its in A, B or both. just iterate over the sorted elements.

Comment: In one case (specifically comparing two std::pair<int,int> type arrays) is about 10% of my frame time on a currently crappy std::set solution).

Comment: @FireLancer `std::set_` should run in O(min(a.size(), b.size()) (for `intersection`, because for `difference` that doesn't make sense). You should benchmark using these against rolling your own with `hash_set`. (Which doesn't require sorting, but does need allocations and has much higher constant factors.)

Comment: @FireLancer - Is getting these "statistics" as you've described constantly done while your app is running?  If not, then go with the simple solution of sorting and calling the `set_intersection` and other functions.

Comment: Don't use `std::set`: sort the vectors.  In theory, you might be able to do it slightly faster just running one loop over the source vectors, but I doubt that the difference would be important.

Comment: Without a range-restricted lookup table, I believe O(NlogN) is the best you're going to get from this, assuming you take the time to sort both ranges as James suggests. If a range-table were possible (commonly used for smaller domains such as `char` or `short`, signed or not), it is feasible in O(N+M), but it doesn't sound like that would be a reasonable fit for your data.

Comment: Its the reported (sampling, windows xperf) profiler time on a release build on the leaf function that does this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's not clear from your question whether you mean
`std::set` when you speak of sorted sets.  If so, then your
first reaction should be to use `std::vector`, if you can, on
the original vectors.  Just sort them, and then:

```
std::vector<T> r1;
std::set_intersection( a.cbegin(), a.cend(), b.cbegin(), b.cend(), std::back_inserter( r1 ) );
```

And the same for `r2` and `r3`.

Beyond that, I doubt that there's much you can do.  Just one
loop might improve things some:

```
std::sort( a.begin(), a.end() );
std::sort( b.begin(), b.end() );
onlyA.reserve( a.size() );
onlyB.reserve( b.size() );
both.reserve( std::min( a.size(), b.size() ) );
auto ita = a.cbegin();
auto enda = a.cend();
auto itb = b.cbegin();
auto endb = b.cend();
while ( ita != enda && itb != endb ) {
    if ( *ita < *itb ) {
        onlyA.push_back( *ita );
        ++ ita;
    } else if ( *itb < *ita ) {
        onlyB.push_back( *itb );
        ++ itb;
    } else {
        both.push_back( *ita );
        ++ ita;
        ++ itb;
    }
}
onlyA.insert( onlyA.end(), ita, enda );
onlyB.insert( onlyB.end(), itb, endb );
```

The `reserve` could make a difference, and unless most of the
elements end up in the same vector, probably won't cost much
extra memory.

Comment: For brevity, the cleanup while loops could be written as calls to `onlyA.insert(onlyA.end(), ita, enda);` and similarly for B.

Comment: @Novelocrat Good point.  I was actually transcribing code that I'd written in Python, where this possibility doesn't exist; it's clearly a better solution.

Comment: This is likely the fastest solution if |A| + |B| is relatively small (like, less than 25 or something). At some point, the O(n) solution will beat out the O(n log(n)) one, though.

Comment: @jxh You mean keeping specially designed hashed structures?  In the past, the measurements I've done suggest that the difference between `std::unordered_map` and `std::map` doesn't really start to make a difference until you have a couple of thousand entries.  (And only then, of course, if you have a good hashing function.)  In this case, the better locality of `std::vector` could mean that you'd need hundreds of thousands of entries before `std::unordered_map` started paying off.  Or not: we'd actually have to measure to be sure.

Comment: I didn't mean the data structure representing the set, I just meant your algorithm in comparison to mine.

Comment: @jxh You're algorithm certainly has a lower O.  But with modern machines, this won't always mean that it will be faster; big-O assumes constant time for things like memory access, which just isn't the case today.  You're algorithm removes data from the middle of a list; keeping things in a list turns out to be an expensive proposition.  I think it would be interesting to benchmark both solutions, to determine where the cut-off point is, but I suspect that it will be in the hundreds of thousands, not 25 or so.

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following algorithm will run O(|A|+|B|) (assuming O(1) behavior from `unordered_map`):

- Let list `onlyA` initially contain all of A, and lists `onlyB` and `bothAB` start out as empty.
- Let hash-table `Amap` associate elements in `onlyA` with its corresponding iterator in `onlyA`.
- For each element *b* in `B`

  - If *b* finds a corresponding iterator *ai* in Amap

    - Add *b* to `bothAB`
    - Remove *b* from `onlyA` using *ai*
  - Otherwise, add *b* to `onlyB`

At the end of the above algorithm,

- onlyA contains elements in A but not in B,
- onlyB contains elements in B but not in A,
- bothAB contains elements in both A and B.

Below is an implementation of the above. The result is returned as a tuple <`onlyA`, `onlyB`, `bothAB`>.

```
template <typename C>
auto venn_ify (const C &A, const C &B) ->
    std::tuple<
        std::list<typename C::value_type>,
        std::list<typename C::value_type>,
        std::list<typename C::value_type>
    >
{
    typedef typename C::value_type T;
    typedef std::list<T> LIST;
    LIST onlyA(A.begin(), A.end()), onlyB, bothAB;
    std::unordered_map<T, typename LIST::iterator> Amap(2*A.size());
    for (auto a = onlyA.begin(); a != onlyA.end(); ++a) Amap[*a] = a;
    for (auto b : B) {
        auto ai = Amap.find(b);
        if (ai == Amap.end()) onlyB.push_back(b);
        else {
            bothAB.push_back(b);
            onlyA.erase(ai->second);
        }
    }
    return std::make_tuple(onlyA, onlyB, bothAB);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in linear time by putting the elements of A into an unordered_map where the elements from A are the keys.  The check if the elements of B in keys in the map.

Comment: That would be O(n * log(N)). Also that is **NOT** how the `std::set_` functions are implemented.

Comment: @Xarn Sorry, I meant unordered_map.  You are correct about the std::set, I just checked the time complexity.